# Upload file error from client side ( jquery )

Tags: c#, jquery, file-upload, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to upload a file from javascript by posting the form using jQuery to my controller action method. I don't want to wait for the result and would like to immediately return. That's why I call `Task.Factory.StartNew` and return bool. But I get error "Cannot access the closed file in the Task body!". Please advise.

```
[HttpPost] 
public bool UploadAll(HttpPostedFileBase fileSelect)
{          
    Task.Factory.StartNew<string>((st) =>
                    {
                        var file = st as HttpPostedFileBase;
                        if (file != null)
                        {
        // Here is where I get the error "cannot access the closed file!"
                            file.SaveAs("E:\\" + file.FileName);
                            return file.FileName;
                        }
                        return string.Empty;
                    }, fileSelect).ContinueWith((tsk) =>
                      {
                          Debug.WriteLine(tsk.Result);
                      });

    return true;
}
```

Client side

```
$(function () {
                //getAllVideos();
                $('#upload').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var files = $("#fileSelect")[0].files;
                    if (files.length > 0) {
                        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {                       
                               var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);                                                          
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: uploadUrl,
                                        method: "post",
                                        cache: false,
                                        contentType: false,
                                        processData: false,
                                        data: formData
                                    }).done(function (result) {
                                        alert(result);
                                    }).fail(function () {
                                    });                          

                });         
            });
        }());
```

Comment: if there are multiple files selected, I don't want to wait for them to be uploaded. Instead I want to kick the uploads to some asyn task in background to return to my jquery call. And the check for the upload status in another javascript call !

Comment: Please the client side code in the inital post body. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is expected as request is closed/disposed when it is "complete" - in this case when you `return true`. Request/response related objects will not be usable past that point which is exactly what you trying to do by delaying reading from input stream.

Fix:

- make server side code to normally store file as part of the request but on client side don't wait for result
- read input stream into `MemoryStream` and save that to a file. May not work for large files.

Comment: What is the best way of doing multiple file upload from client side using <input type="file" multiple /> in parallel. I means posting the files to server and display progress of each file upload status?